# Why unity pauses itself while I am in playing mode?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pause

I am making a 2D game in unity platform. Mine problem is about pause function. When I test my game, after a while unity stops playing mode. Therefore, I am pressing the pause button a lot to continue playing mode. Every time I click the pause button, unity passes playing mode for few seconds. After couple of clicks, unity returns to its regular mechanism. Then, this situation happens again after playing a bit more. I deleted unity and installed from scratch. But it didn't work. Is there any suggestion that I can apply?

My unity version is 5.3.2f1 and here is my screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you add break point in your script?

Answer (score 4):

Its a long time but i guess solution can help others, basically you have to turn off **Error Pause** from Console Tab: [Unity editor itself paused while in playing mode](https://answers.unity.com/questions/29176/when-i-press-play-it-just-pauses-right-after.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found this problem is usually the result of a script throwing an error. Check the Console Window for what your error is while Unity is paused. In my case, I had inadvertently dropped a script on an object without realizing it, thus resulting in object reference errors (none of the public variables were set) and the behavior you described above. While in pause mode, click on the error and Unity will show you which object called the script. Double click the error to edit your script at the point the error occurred.